# What is the name of the person whose role is to be the first contact for complaints?

Tags: word-request, phrase-request, vocabulary, terminology

What is the general name of first contact person who is initially approached/contacted for any complain?

If for example, I am part of an industry and I work in chemical engineering department and I have seen a problem relevant to electrical engineering department, 
I will inform electrical engineering department, but the person who receives complain from me at first in electrical engineering department, what will be he called for this role first contact person?

Or there isn't any special name for this/such role?

Comment: I think you mean to use the word “complaint” instead of “complain”. For example, *I complain to Janet. She documents my complaint and forwards it to the appropriate department.*

Answer (score 1):

Well, in most cases, the person would be "Customer service representative".

Answer (score 1):

I have worked in such a role. Typically, and specifically, it's called ***front line*** *support* (or *Tier 1 support*, *level 1 support*, or *first-line support*).

From ["What it’s like on the front lines of support"](https://www.zendesk.com/blog/like-front-lines-support/) at Zendesk:

> Here’s what a few agents on the front lines of our Tier 1 support had to say about their agent experience: …
>
> **Three things support agents on the front lines see most:**
>
> At Zendesk, our T1 advocates filter through and solve a majority of tickets (roughly 80 percent), which means they see everything. While no two support configurations are exactly alike, beyond core troubleshooting and account questions, here are a few common things support agents can expect on the front lines, according to our very own agents:
>
> **1. Use cases**
>   At Zendesk, the front lines see how our own products work—for both admins and agents. Not only do our T1 agents help customers with the product all day, but our agents work in the product as well. When helping customers, our agents usually work on Administrative tasks and permissions. However, when they use Zendesk themselves, agents like Leah constantly discover more about the Zendesk agent experience, seeing what works about the product and what doesn’t from both perspectives.
>
> **2. Feedback**
>   Working on the front lines offers valuable information throughout the day, from direct product feedback to customers who describe their task flow as they’re doing it over the the phone. That’s a lot of useful feedback, and it’s important to utilize all of the feedback that comes in. We provide feedback to our own product team, which is relayed to our engineers so they can evolve our software. …
>
> **Conclusion**
>
> First-line support can be a lively place to be and there’s plenty of useful information agents can gleam from every interaction. While it can be difficult to do, consistently reminding your support teams to think about utilizing feedback and use cases to educate customers can greatly improve the front lines of your company’s support. All it takes is a moment to step back from the front lines to gain perspective.